# adding event to android calendar without showing the calendar

Tags: android

i have this code for adding event:

```
Intent calendarIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT, Events.CONTENT_URI);

Calendar beginTime = Calendar.getInstance();
beginTime.set(2013,04,14,21,00,00);

Calendar endTime = Calendar.getInstance();
endTime.set(2013,04,14,21,10,00);
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT);
intent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/event");
intent.putExtra("title", "Some title");
intent.putExtra("description", "Some description");
intent.putExtra("beginTime", beginTime.getTimeInMillis());
intent.putExtra("endTime", endTime.getTimeInMillis());
startActivity(intent);
```

but how to insert event without open the calendar ?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

you need use a `ContentResolver` instead `Intent`

```
ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

Calendar beginTime = Calendar.getInstance();
beginTime.set(2013,04,14,21,00,00);

Calendar endTime = Calendar.getInstance();
endTime.set(2013,04,14,21,10,00);

values.put(Events.DTSTART, beginTime.getTimeInMillis());
values.put(Events.DTEND, endTime.getTimeInMillis());
values.put(Events.TITLE, "Some title");
values.put(Events.DESCRIPTION, "Some description");

Uri uri = cr.insert(Events.CONTENT_URI, values);
```

you can read more [Calendar Provider](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider.html#calendar)

Comment: thanks for the help !, but i got error on this line:  Uri uri = cr.insert(Events.CONTENT_URI, values);

Comment: my api is 14+ and still error on  Uri uri = cr.insert(Events.CONTENT_URI, values);

Comment: i have in my phone account and i got this error: : E/AndroidRuntime(10099): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Event values must include a calendar_id

Comment: yeah in the documentation show in example `values.put(Events.CALENDAR_ID, calID);` maybe you must show to the user a list of available calendars and choose one

Comment: How can I specify the account to which the events are saved to?